# Distinguishing Files From Directories

Tags: python

So I'm sure this is a stupid question, but I've looked through Python's documentation and attempted a couple of Google codes and none of them has worked.

It seems like the following should work, but it returns "False" for 
In my directory /foo/bar I have 3 items: 1 Folder "[Folder]", 1 file "test" (no extension), and 1 file "test.py".

I'm look to have a script that can distinguish folders from files for a bunch of functions, but I can't figure out anything that works.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, re
for f in os.listdir('/foo/bar'):
    print f, os.path.isdir(f)
```

Currently returns false for everything.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3761473/69772

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `listdir()` returns the names of the files in `/foo/bar`. When you later do `os.path.isdir()` on one of these, the OS interprets it relative to the *current working directory* which is probably the directory your script is in, not `/foo/bar`, and it probably does not contain a directory of the specified name. A path that doesn't exist is not a directory and so `isdir()` returns `False.`.

Use the complete pathname. Best way is to use `os.path.join`, e.g., `os.path.isdir(os.path.join('/foo/bar', f))`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `os.walk` instead: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk

When it returns the contents of the directory, it returns files and directories in separate lists, negating the need for checking.

So you could do:

```
import os

root, dirs, files = next(os.walk('/foo/bar'))

print 'directories:', dirs
print 'files:', files
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `os.path.isdir(os.path.join('/foo/bar', f))` should work.