# python os.listdir no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I know it might sounds dumb to you but im learning Python right now by following course on the internet and they ask us to create a kind of labyrinth.
They give a "base code", but when I try to run it, it says **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cartes'**, the error is in os.listdir(cards). 
I would like the code to list the contents of a local directory named `cartes` but am unable to do so because I receive the **FileNotFoundError**.

This is the code that I'm struggling with:

```
# -*-coding:Utf-8 -*

"""This file contains the main code of the game.

Run him with Python to start the game.

"""

import os

from map import Map

# We load the existing maps
maps = []
for file_name in os.listdir("maps"):
    if file_name.endswith(".txt"):
        path = os.path.join("maps", nom_fichier)
        map_name = file_name[:-3].lower()
        with open(path, "r") as file:
            content = file.read()
            # Map creation, to complete

# We display the existing maps
print("Existing labyrinths :")
for i, map in enumerate(maps):
    print("  {} - {}".format(i + 1, map.nom))

# If there is a saved game, we display it, to complete

# ... Complete the program ...
```

Comment: next time please include the code in the body of your post :)

Comment: where are you running the command from? I think I've found the problem

Comment: yes, the error is in os.listdit("cartes")

Comment: Can you please translate the French words in your code to English?

Comment: It is now translated in english

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761473/python-not-recognising-directories-os-path-isdir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the directory is local (you haven't specified the WHOLE file path, eg `C:\Users....\roboc` the script can only find this folder if it's in the same directory has been run.

Open terminal and navigate to the `roboc` folder. then run `python roboc.py` and that should provide a quick fix :)

Or try this

```
import os

from map import Map

# We load the existing maps
maps = []
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
maps_path = os.path.join(script_path, "maps")
for file_name in os.listdir(maps_path):
    if file_name.endswith(".txt"):
        path = os.path.join(maps_path, nom_fichier)
        map_name = file_name[:-3].lower()
        with open(path, "r") as file:
            content = file.read()
            # Map creation, to complete

# We display the existing maps
print("Existing labyrinths :")
for i, map in enumerate(maps):
    print("  {} - {}".format(i + 1, map.nom))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but people are going to evaluate my work, so I would like it work by only running the file (without navigating in the terminal).

Comment: check this answer out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799353/python-giving-filenotfounderror-though-the-file-exists they've explained it better than I can

Comment: If I understand, the error in this "answer" is when he tries to open the file (open (filename,'r')). I think my error is the path of "os.listdir()" and not of "with open()". What I wanna do is use a relative path (is this how you call it in english?) to get to the files. (Have you seen my folder image ?)

Comment: yeah, that's fine you just need to run your script from the same directory as the folder your interested in. How are you running your script?

Comment: from the terminal (macOS), I write python3 ... (path)

Comment: What I would like is to make it work only by writing python3 ... (path), if this is possible

Comment: yeah, when you open the terminal try `cd ... (path to the python file)` then from there run `python3 roboc.py`

Comment: I know that but is there a way the person evaluating me won’t have to do that? Can I write something like os.chdir("current file") in the roboc.py?

Comment: yeah - here's how to do that, let me update my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934806/how-can-i-find-scripts-directory-with-python